# Render file that was just uploaded in react

Tags: reactjs

I want to immediately display the user a file he/she just uploaded in ReactJS. Currently, I am using this code. The image file is not being rendered in the img tag.
[image]
[image]( <--PS this is not an issue in image rendering issue in StackOverflow or on your browser. This is how the looks)

```js
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function Upload() {
    const [uploadedFile, setuploadedFile] = useState(null);

    return (
        <div>
            <label htmlFor='upload-design'>
                {uploadedFile ? 
                    <img src={uploadedFile} /> :
                    <div>{/* some HTML here*/}</div>}
            </label>
            <input id='upload-design' type='file' onChange={e => setuploadedFile(e.target.files[0])} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly show the file input value in `<img src=''/>` tag.
First you need to convert file input value into `base64` then show in `<img />` tag

Try below code it's works !

```
function App() {
  const [uploadedFile, setuploadedFile] = useState(null);

  const base64FileURL = (element, callback) => {
    let file = element;
    let reader = new window.FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function (e) {
      callback(e.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }

  const handleFileChange = (file) => {
    base64FileURL(file, (obj) => {
      setuploadedFile(obj);
    });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <label htmlFor='upload-design'>
        {uploadedFile ?
          <img src={uploadedFile} /> :
          <div>{/* some HTML here*/}</div>}
      </label>
      <input id='upload-design' type='file' onChange={e => handleFileChange(e.target.files[0])} />
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```